# Swift 5 Delgate does not call method in ViewController

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I have the following scenario:
The PermissionView appears when MyViewController loads. When I tap on the ok, the okButtonPressed func inside of PermissionView executes.

However, the permissionGiven func inside of MyViewController, doesn't execute.

I'm left with PermissionView staying active on my screen.

```
@objc protocol PermissionViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    
    func permissionDenied(_ sender: UIButton)
    func permissionGiven(_ sender: UIButton)
}

class PermissionView: UIView {
 
    @IBOutlet var cancelButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var okButton: UIButton!
    
    weak var delegate: PermissionViewDelegate?
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let permissionView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PermissionView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! PermissionView
    
        self.addSubview(permissionView)
        self.frame = frame
        
        okButton = permissionView.okButton
        
        cancelButton = permissionView.cancelButton
        
    }

    @IBAction func okButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("ok!")
        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(PermissionViewDelegate.permissionGiven(_:))) ?? false {
            delegate?.permissionGiven(sender)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("cancel!")
        if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(PermissionViewDelegate.permissionDenied(_:))) ?? false {
            delegate?.permissionDenied(sender)
        }
    }
}
```

In another ViewController, I have the following:

```
class MyViewController: PermissionViewDelegate { // implements other delegates as well

    private var permissionView: PermissionView?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if !(permissionView != nil) {
            permissionView = PermissionView(frame: view.frame)
            permissionView?.delegate = self
            
            permissionView?.setImage(UIImage(named: "permission_notification"))
            
            //other properties set

            view.addSubview(permissionView!)
            
            permissionView?.center = view.center
        }
    func permissionGiven(_ sender: UIButton) {
        permissionView?.removeFromSuperview()
        
        Utils.setBoolForKey(true, forKey: Utils.NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION())
        Utils.setBoolForKey(true, forKey: Utils.NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_VIEWED())
         
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.registerForNotifications()
        
        enableControls()
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The delegate is the controller not the view. Btw why are you connecting the buttons to the view instead of the controller?

Comment: PermissionView was pre-existing it's an .xib and contains the two buttons. All the others are in the storyboard. It appears overtop of a few different ViewControllers if required to do so.

Comment: If I understood `print("ok!")` is called, but then, is `delegate` nil? Or `delegate?.responds(to: #selector(PermissionViewDelegate.permissionGiven(_:)))` returning `false`? Also, what's self when the method is called? Is it the added view (the one you did with `addSubview()`, or the one itself?

Comment: so the delegate inside of okPressed is nil. Not quite sure why. Do I need to change the way things are initialized?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you need, is delete the next lines, because you don't need to check  `responds` methods, only need to ckech If delegate is not nil, although you are already doing it with the flag '?'

```
if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(PermissionViewDelegate.permissionGiven(_:))) ?? false { }

if delegate?.responds(to: #selector(PermissionViewDelegate.permissionDenied(_:))) ?? false {
```